# Localhost integers are strings, but numeric on production

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

My Laravel blade template has this piece of code:

```
<script>
 var options = {!!$selection->options()->pluck('options.id')!!};
</script>
```

The output on localhost is

```
var options = [2, 4];
```

But on production environment

```
var options = ["2", "4"];
```

How do I make them the same across all the environments?

Comment: Normalize (enforce) `options` to contain numbers (or string)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you apply any logic to convert to string or convert to integer like we do in Java."Integer.parseInt()".
Hope this you can get some idea with this for your code.

Comment: Was hoping there would be a blade answer. I went for `options = options.map(Number);`